# Using "for the light of space" to mean "for the lack of space"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, vocabulary

The following statement appears in an academic paper I am reading:

> Mathematical derivations are omitted for the light of space.

As a native English speaker, I find the use of *light* in this sentence highly unusual. Presumably the author (a non-native speaker) intends to say *for lack of space*. Is the phrase "light of space" semantically correct? Is there such an idiom, or a synonym for "light" that means "lack"?

Comment: It's maybe a composite error. The meaning may be 'in the light of lack of space'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is almost certainly based on an error.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for the feedback. I do not see how your suggestion to close this question as off-topic is remotely constructive or helpful to the goals of this site, which is to ask well-formed and reasonable questions about the English language, and receive answers from the community. Could you kindly point me to the specific website standard that this question violates for it ot warrant closure?

Comment: Lack of any signs of research are almost always a sufficient close-vote reason on ELU. Boondoggle supplies a link which could have accompanied the question. But as Andrew Leach says, it's guesswork as to what the author actually intended. // If ELU accepted questions asking for explanations concerning every typo, spelling mistake, ungrammatical internet example, unclear phrasing and the like, it would degenerate into mediocrity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Should I delete the question? Or how do you suggest I rephrase it so that it is relevant, if at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is confusing `for the light of` with "[in the light of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_the_light_of_%28or_in_light_of%29)" and likely means `considering`.

> Mathematical derivations are omitted considering limited space.

Comment: It may even have been an editorial slip, intending either "for the lack of" or "in the light of" and ending up with neither.